# Why might one need to set "supported document types" for an iOS or macOS build?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

Documentation in XCode says the following:

> You can configure your app to support different document types. You
>   can edit the document types setting in the Info pane for the target,
>   or by editing the information property list directly.
>
> Go to CFBundleDocumentTypes in Information Property List Key Reference
>   for the possible values for the CFBundleTypeName (Name field),
>   LSItemContentTypes (Types field), CFBundleTypeRole, and other keys
>   that appear in the Info.plist file.

It does not however say *what* different document types are for, nor *why* you might want or need them.

What are they for, please?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify which kind of documents your (document-based) App can open (read-only or read-write).

E.g. a word processor App might want to open `.txt` files for reading and writing and also offer the possibility to display `.doc` files.

The information you provide in the plist file is used by the OS to register your App in the Launch Services DB. I.e. double clicking a `.txt` file will then open your application with the document, Finder will show the provided icon, etc.

Comment: Thanks @mschmidt. I won't mark this as the answer *yet* because although I'm sure you're right, it was a largely academic question at this stage, and I won't be able to be verify it for a while.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.